# Resolved - Reading Database Table Info in Magento Way

Tags: magento-1.9, module, database, custom, query

I'm using this simple PHP code below to read data from my module's table, but can't do the same thing using Magento codes.

Tried to do that using different articles but was either getting errors or the whole table structure was displayed in the page instead of just the information.

How can I do that?

```
    <?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "dbname";

   // Create connection
   $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
  // Check connection
   if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
   } 

   $sql = "SELECT comment_txt, name, comment_date FROM mytablename where productcomment_increment_id='$productId' && comment_status='Approved'";
   $result = $conn->query($sql);

   if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<i><b>Author Name:</b></i>";
        echo $row["name"];
        echo "<br /><i><b> Comment: </i></b>";
        echo $row["comment_txt"];
        echo "<br /><i><b>Date: </i></b>";
        echo $row["comment_date"];
        echo "<br><br>";
    }
   } else {
   //echo "0 results";
   }
   $conn->close();
   ?>
```

I will greatly appreciate helpful answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below mentioned code

```
//database read adapter 

$read = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read'); 

$results = $read->fetchAll("select * from your_tablename"); 
foreach($results as $row)
{
    echo "<i><b>Author Name:</b></i>";
    echo $row["name"];
    echo "<br /><i><b> Comment: </i></b>";
    echo $row["comment_txt"];
    echo "<br /><i><b>Date: </i></b>";
    echo $row["comment_date"];
    echo "<br><br>";
}
```

[For more read here.](http://www.codexpedia.com/magento/magento-direct-mysql-query-for-create-read-update-and-delete/)

Comment: Thanks @Arunendra , but it displays the database structure, not just the values. I'll attach a screenshot, please take a look. How can I fix that?

Comment: @bestwebdevs It's working fine as you can see the output in the given picture.

Comment: Yes, but I need to display values separately, not the whole table structure. Like "Name" : "Ben",  "Comment" : "Some comment text...". Could you help me do that? Thanks @Arunendra

Comment: How do I get a particular column value instead of the whole table structure and values?

Comment: @bestwebdevs I have updated the answer plz check .

Comment: Thanks a ton @Arunendra, I spent so much time on this.. Works just like I wanted :)